# Boundary of the image of the unit disk under the exponential map.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Anyone know the Cartesian coordinate equation for the top half of the boundary of the image of the unit disk under the exponential map in $\mathbb{C}$? Finding parametric equations in Cartesian coordinates was easy enough: 
$$ 
x(t)=\exp(t)\cos(\sqrt{1 - t^2})\\
y(t)=\exp(t)\sin(\sqrt{1 - t^2})\\
-1\leq t\leq 1
$$
I was also able to describe the curve in polar coordinates:
$$
r(\theta)=\exp(\pm\sqrt{1-{\theta}^2})\\
-1\leq \theta\leq 1
$$
I haven't had any luck finding an equation for $y$ as a function of $x$ for the top half of this curve, however.

Comment: Well, $$\begin{align}\bigl(y(t)\bigr)^2 &= \exp(2t)\sin^2\left(\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)\\ &= \exp(2t)\left(1-\cos^2\left(\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)\right)\\ &= \exp(2t)-\bigl(x(t)\bigr)^2,\end{align}$$ so since we're dealing with $y(t)\geq 0$, then $y(t)=\sqrt{\exp(2t)-\bigl(x(t)\bigr)^2}$. Unfortunately, this still depends on $t$ (and there may be no way out of that).

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 + y^2 = \exp(2t)$ so $t = \ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.  Also $\tan \sqrt{1-t^2} = y/x$ with $0 \le \sqrt{1-t^2} \le 1$
so $\arctan(y/x) = \sqrt{1-t^2}$. Thus you have the implicit equation

$$ \left(\ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2 + \left(\arctan(y/x)\right)^2 = 1$$

You won't get a closed-form solution for $y$ as a function of $x$.